# Embedding libmicrohttpd code in C++ OR how to compile this example?

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I have a requirement of creating a C++ program which exposes certain functions through HTTP. For that reason I was trying to use [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/) for the same. Now this library is written in C. However I am kind of new to C++ and am trying to compile this C and C++ code given [here](http://nipun-linuxtips.blogspot.in/2012/09/a-simple-rest-framework-on-cc.html). ([Which can be git cloned from here](https://github.com/nipuntalukdar/NipunTalukdarExamples/tree/master/cpp/restfrmwork))

Now I need help in understanding how g++ may be used to compile a program which is not written completely in C++. And/or how to compile the above linked code.

PS: Working in linux
And finally if someone can point to an easier alternative than libmicrohttpd - I am  all ears.

**Edit to Edit:**
Finally got it working. Compiled the individual cpp files with gcc and then linked everything using g++. I have no clue how this came to work, maybe some one can reply below.
I have made the following script to compile and link:

```
LOC="path/to/directory"
gcc -c httphandler.cpp -o httphandler.o -I $LOC
gcc -c strutil.cpp -o strutil.o -I $LOC
gcc -c api.cpp -o api.o -I $LOC
gcc -c executor.cpp -o executor.o -I $LOC
g++ -o out httphandler.o strutil.o api.o executor.o -lmicrohttpd -lboost_regex
```

<s>But in the final step I am getting the following error:</s>

```
/usr/bin/ld: strutil.o: undefined reference to symbol '__cxa_free_exception@@CXXABI_1.3'
/usr/bin/ld: note: '__cxa_free_exception@@CXXABI_1.3' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
```

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, don't compile the C code with `g++`, use `gcc` instead. Then just include the header file and use the functions normally. When linking don't forget to link with the object file(s) generated from compiling the libmicrohttpd source file(s).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into the right direction. So I did as you said. I have come close(read very few errors). Now I am finally getting a linker error. I am adding it into the question itself. Can you take a look?

Comment: @digvijay91 Compile the C++ code with `g++` and the C code with `gcc`. Link with `g++`. In the snippet you show in your question, it's all C++, so only use `g++`, I thought you compiled libmicrohttpd together with your project.

Comment: Ok I got it working. I used g++ for linking all the object files, along with the -lmicrohttpd and -lboost_regex. But I have no clue as to why it started working. If you add this to your answer, I will accept it, and make the necessary changes in my answer for any future reference(for myself or others).

Comment: @digvijay91 The difference between `gcc` and `g++` when linking is that `g++` by default links with the C++ runtime library, which `gcc` does not.